# Postscript viewer for TeXlive in TeXstudio

Tags: texlive, texstudio, viewers, ps

Due to defective MikTeX installation, which I have not been able to fix for several months now after several unsuccessful trials of de- and reinstallations, I migrated to TeXlive. My documents run again now, which is fine. However I was not able to implement a PS viewer like Yap! which is used for TeXstudio with MikTeX. The default setting after installing TeXlive and TeXstudio afterwards is that TeXstudio uses Irvanview as PS viewer because it is on my system. But Irvanview gives me errors that it cannot display the files. PDFs with Adobe or Sumatra are fine after compilation. So it is not a compilation problem. But most of the time I don't need to open the PDF, but just want a preview.

I tried to install Yap! by itself, but however, after setting the PS-path in TeXstudio configuration to this, this just shows me an empty window which is completely different in general from the window I know from MikTeX's Yap!, besides not showing/opening any content.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I haven't found an answer for this in my research. How do I set up an internal PS viewer in TeXstudio using TeXlive?

**Edit**:

I try to clarify. I usually compile with xe- or lualatex. Now that I reinstalled TeXstudio after TeXlive I recognized that Irvanview opens instead of the preview and gives me error. The only path in TeXstudo that shows Irvanview is ps-path, so I thought there is a misconfiguration. Can you please tell me how to configurate these paths without getting unwanted programs and their errors? I can set the pdf-path there, but that is not a preview then anymore. Or do you all usually use pdf (adobe, sumatra, etc.) there? Maybe I am just not used to that.

Comment: Do you *need* a PS viewer nowadays?

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question right... Maybe I used the wrong words. I want a previewer, which opens after compilation of the document. I thought that these internal previewers I know from MikTeX are easier to handle than just to open a pdf - at least when it comes to recompilation, where you get errors when you forget to close the pdf, which happens quite often to me. But you are right, that I do not *need* it in that sense. As I said, pdf output is fine. I am just very used to the MikTeX previewer that I am looking for an TeXlive alternative if there is any.

Comment: TeXStudio has an internal PDF previewer.

Comment: But what is its name? I deinstalled every TeX-related programs, then installed TeXlive and afterwards installed TeXstudio. And TeXstudio choose to use Irvanview. Obviously TeXstudio is not using its own previewer.

Comment: Do you need to compile to dvi/ps? Why don't you use pdflatex or lualatex and compile directly to pdf? There are fast pdf viewers (e.g. sumatra or the build-in pdfviewers in texstudio).

Comment: In the “Build” tab of the preferences, choose “Internal PDF Viewer (Embedded)” for “PDF Viewer”.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am not sure. Even when I compiled my documents with LuaLaTeX I received this preview. So I am not sure. Concerning your questions I guess I am not that deep in materia. In MikTeX I always got this 'easy' preview and am wondering now how to get that with TeXlive, too. I have to admit that I don't know if these steps inbetween are neccessary.

Comment: @egreg I tried that, then an window with text (`WARNING - the DELAYBIND command has been deprecated`) opens and I get an error message `psview couldn't be created`. The Ps setting is `"C:/texlive/2017/bin/win32/psv.exe" %.ps`. I guess there is something wrong in my settings.

Comment: as far as I can tell you do not want a postscript previewer (and were not using postscript output in miktex) you may want to edit the question

Comment: lualatex and yap are rather incompatible. lualatex creates a pdf.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I don't understand. Please do you edit the question with right terms as I still don't know how to express.
@ UlrikeFischer then I guess it was not yap althought that was shown in the path in TeXstudio. So this is everything I rely on.

Comment: I can't really answer in detail as I don't have miktex or texstudio, but what makes you ask for _postscript_ previewer? latex makes dvi or pdflatex makes pdf, to make postscript you need to use latex to get a dvi file then use dvips to convert that to postscript, it is possible to install ghostscript based postscript viewers but that is rather rare to do these days, pdf by design replaced almost all on screen postscript use (pdf was invented by the same company that invented postscript, specifically to be a version better for on screen viewing)

Comment: Ok, I try to clarify. I usually compile with xe- or lualatex. Now that I reinstalled texstudio I recognized that irvanview opens instead of the preview and gives me error. The only path in texstudo that shows irvanview is ps-path, so I thought there is a misconfiguration. Can you please tell me how to configurate these paths without getting unwanted programs and their errors? I can set the pdf-path there, but that is not a preview then anymore. Or do you all usually use pdf (adobe, sumatra, etc.) there? Maybe I am just not used to that.

Comment: I don't have to insist on this preview. I was just used to it due MikTex and until before my question thought this would be the usual way of LaTeX to handle things. What are the settings for TeXlive with TeXstudio? Do you all just use pdf directly?

Comment: Anyway, it can be helpful to have a ps viewer. You can download  `Ghostcript 9.23`  and its interface `Gsview 6.0 beta`from [Artifex site](http://www.gsview.com/).

Comment: Irfan View can be configured as the default viewer for many file types. Apparently, you have set it to be the default viewer for *.ps files. Open Irfan View, find its preferences, and un-check the file type. Also, Windows may be steering your *.ps files there. Right-click a *.ps file, and when the context menu appears, try "open with." You can also try the "properties," and see if the default program for *.ps can be re-assigned. Windows will not automatically find the TeXlive built-in programs, because they did not announce themselves to the system, during installation.

Comment: Please take screenshots of your `Configure TeXstudio->Commands` and `Configure TeXstudio->Build` page and show it here.

Comment: it is highly unlikely that you were using postscript preview with your previous miktex setup, neither xetex nor luatex can make postscript output, so to get from the output of either you would need to run a conversion from dvi or pdf to get to postscript before viewing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle With your explanations I managed to find my mistake. The default viewer was set to PS viewer. Since xelatex does not generate PS it could not show anything. I changed the default viewer to PDF viewer and now get the internal Texstudio preview I want. Do you want to make your descriptions an answer? Or shall I edit my question?

Comment: @Lysanne it may be better if you post an answer as you can say what you did, I just helped clarify a few terms but didn't really understand the problem as I don't use that editor or viewer.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the discussion I learned that XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX do not generate PS files. So the problem was not the path to the PS viewer. With no PS generated there can't be PS preview. However, since I newly installed TeXstudio the default previewer was set to PS, which seems to be the default configuration of TeXstudio. I changed the default previewer to PDF and now get the internal TeXstudio preview I desired.